# Sending data from GPS Device to my web application

Tags: gps

I am trying a to develop a web application(ASP.Net) that should track the position of a vehicle (with a gps device installed in it).

My problems are I do not have any idea on how to communicate with the device and get the coordinates.
Is there any care(any ISO standard like that i need to know) I need to take before buying the device?

Comment: You still have a thousand unknowns, but look at gpsd (http://www.catb.org/gpsd/) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. Just make sure the GPS is NMEA compatible. Almost every device is. The best and cheapest GPS modules are the uBlox NEO-6M based GPSes. If you don't care about getting a PCB with a uBlox chip and an antenna, you can get these for about $20 (USD) or less. These devices are accurate, and "speaks" NMEA and uBlox binary protocol. They also have PPS (Pulse-Per-Second) output on pin 3 which makes them great for a time server.

In order to tranfer data to a server, you need to connect the GPS to something like a computer with an internet connection. A "computer" could be a microcontroller (like the Arduino, Raspberry Pi, etc) or just a good old PC. In theory you could skip the computer, but then you loose control and would have to transmit all data from the GPS all the time.